# MVC3 Customizing DropdownList items in strongly typed view

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an auto generated DropDownList from Entity Framework in a strongly typed view:

```
 <div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownList("User_FK", String.Empty)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User_FK)
</div>
```

[image: Auto Generated drop down list]

Here is the action code:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.SystemMaster_FK = new SelectList(db.SystemMasters, "System_PK", "Name");
    ViewBag.User_FK = new SelectList(db.Users, "User_PK", "NetworkLogin");
    return View();
}
```

I need this list to display the names of people loaded from Active Directory. How do I customize the select list options seperately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Html.DropDownList` has another overload, namely:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DropDownList(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string name,
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList
)
```

So, you specify a `name` string and then an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` generated any way you want.

So, (of course, I'm assuming some types here--`MyUserType`, `MyActiveDirectoryRepository`)

```
List<MyUserType> users = new List<MyUserType>();

foreach(var user in MyActiveDirectoryRepository.GetUsers())
{
    users.Add(new MyUserType()
    {
        ADName = user.Username,
        ID = user.ID // or SAM token, or something similar
    });
}
```

Pass the list to your view via <s>View Model pattern</s> ViewBag

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    // populate list as above
    ViewBag.User_FK = new SelectList(users, "ID", "ADName");
    return View();
}
```

Then, after passing it to your view (preferably, via view model *not* ViewBag)

```
@Html.DropDownList("NameOfDropDown", ViewBag.User_FK)
```

Comment: CreateViewModel() doesn't exist or i don't know where to find it. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @Tjaart Sorry--I forgot to mention that in my list of assumed types. It's a plain class containing a `List<MyUserType>` property named `MyList`--it's nothing more than a means of wrapping the model sent to your view. Hence, "View Model"

Comment: It doesnt see the MyList in my view. Maybe because my model is already defined in my view as `@model SystemInformationManager.Models.SystemMaintainer`

Comment: @Tjaart I assumed there was no model according to your `Create` action method. `return View();` doesn't send a model to the view. Are you able to get inside `SystemMaintainer`? If not, you may have to wrap it in `CreateViewModel` and modify any existing view code that uses the SystemMaintainer properties.

Comment: Ok. I got it working. I had to change the selectlist in the controller action to `ViewBag.User_FK = new SelectList(users, "ID", "ADName");` where users is my custom user type. The reason an object isn't passed to the view is that the Create is loading the form to insert into the SystemMaintainer table. `SystemMaintainer` is accessible but as a new object. Are you willing to edit your answer to reflect what works. I will change the question to make it clear that it is a strongly typed view. Thank you!

Comment: @Tjaart Please review my answer to be sure I didn't miss anything. I modified View Model to ViewBag and changed the member names of the `MyUserType`